# How to create a project package for Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I need to create a project for umbraco. I Don't know where to start and where to see about this. I googled and found nothing helpful instead I got confused what is umbraco project. To create a umbraco project whether I need to create web applications or class library in visual studio.

I know these are basic but I'm confused in that only. would somebody help me to create the project for umbraco CMS.

Comment: not sure what you mean, what do you exactly want wo achieve? Have you already saw the video's on http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials.aspx ...this is a good start about umbraco.

Comment: What do want to do? It`s not clear from your question what this Umbraco project will do.

Comment: I need to create a project for umbraco. projects like Newsletter Studio, uBlogsy ,etc.

Comment: @GopinathPerumal I too want to know how to create a project from base (starting from creating application in visual studio) a step by step process. would someone help!

Comment: @GopinathPerumal, your question isn't specific enough. Creating a package in Umbraco is easy, there are however, many different ways to extend Umbraco's functionality. Please consider revising your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for resources on how to create an Umbraco Package.

Once you have come up with a way to extend the functionality of Umbraco (ie: a new data type, a new section, some event handlers that are fired on publish, etc), you'll want to find a way to package that up and redistribute it, possibly even on [Our Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/projects). There are a couple ways to go about doing this:

1. **The Umbraco backoffice comes with a way to package up document types, data types, templates, assemblies, etc.:**

   1. In the **Developer** section, expand **Packages**.
   2. Right-click **Created packages**, and choose **Create**.
   3. Fill in package details, select content and files, write package actions, etc.
2. **Create packages within Visual Studio using MSBuild**. This is a more advanced (and therefore complicated) approach. I've found it helpful to look at the source code of some of the popular packages out there, such as [uComponents](http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d4d3e337953d#BuildPackage/BuildPackage.msbuild), to get a good understanding on how this is done.

The package file is simply a zip file that contains xml with instructions for Umbraco on what to do when it is installed.

Comment: I need to create a package which includes(In Backoffice) a new icon like content, media, dev, etc., in that section options to add, view and save person details like name, address ,etc., as a list. (in Site)I have a signup user control when a person signup in that page it should add, save and show his/her details in backoffice. I have done this using visual studio as a web application. but how to make that as a umbraco package. Please help me to achieve that.