# Umbraco add dashboard with code

Tags: customization, umbraco, dashboard

Ok, with some help I found the code to add a new application / section without modifying the config manually. Add an assmebly with this class in the /bin folder and the section is automatically added to Umbraco.

```
[Application("guestbook", "Guestbook", ".trayguestbook", 20)]
public class Class1 : IApplication
{
```

Then you can modify the Tree by adding a class that inherits from BaseTree.

```
[Tree("guestbook", "guestbookTree", "Guestbook")]
public class Class2 : BaseTree
{
```

Is there a way to modify the dashboard with a similair approach as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't a code first approach to modifying the dashboard.config. However, if you wrap your project into an Umbraco package, you can use [package actions](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/packaging/package-actions) to [add a dashboard section](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/packaging/package-actions/add-dashboard-section). Here's an example from the documentation:

```xml
<Action runat="install" alias="addDashboardSection" dashboardAlias="MyDashboardSection">
  <section>
    <areas>
      <area>default</area>
      <area>content</area>
    </areas>
    <tab caption="Last Edits">
      <control>/usercontrols/latestEdits.ascx</control>
      <control>/usercontrols/PostCreate.ascx</control>
    </tab>
    <tab caption="Create blog post">
      <control>/usercontrols/new.ascx</control>
    </tab>
  </section>
</Action>
```

For more details on package actions see [Package Action Samples](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/packages-and-projects/package-action-samples). For more information of creating Umbraco packages see [How to create a project package for Umbraco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008641/how-to-create-a-project-package-for-umbraco).