# Most efficient way to update all solution by single change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have developed one product in umbraco CMS(Restaurant Booking).

This solution was sell in 10 restaurant.

Every Restaurant have its own domain.

Now i need to some changes in that like css changes etc.

Is there any way to update all the solution by one click like updation in application like whats app update ?

or is there any other way to make product in Umbraco?

Regards,
Ronak Panchal.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should make your product into an Umbraco package, this way you would encapsulate everything into a single bundle that you could then deploy to your clients using the Package manager in Umbraco.

Here is a stackoverflow Q&A on how to create a package:

[How to create a project package for Umbraco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008641/how-to-create-a-project-package-for-umbraco)

One of the other advantages is once you have created it you will be able to send out other updates in the same way, also you will be able to look at their installation and see which version of the package they are using.

Hope this helps